# How to find a folder based on numerical order [on bash cli]

Tags: directory

I'm dealing with huge image data and it's following like

```
/root/folder1
/root/folder2
/root/folder3
/root/folder4
...
```

However in fact, the subfolder names are not explicitly written with numbers.

So, if I want to find 230th order of folder, I have to count one by one.
How can I find it smartly?

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of order do you count? according to name, size, date, ...?

Comment: according to name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we don't know how you order them, I'm just going to assume it's alphabetically, in which case run the following in a terminal:

```
cd /enter/dir/here
ls | sort | head -n 230 | tail -n 1
```

This will sort `ls` alphabetically, only get the first 230 results, and then grab the last one of those 230.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's quite easier than I thought

Comment: If you want to know all the numbers you can do `ls | sort | nl`

Comment: `sed -n '230p'` would be a little bit easier than `head -n 230 | tail -n 1
`

Answer (score 1):

I usually use `bash`, however this is one of those tasks for which you might want to consider switching to `zsh` so that you can use its [glob qualifiers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Filename-Generation)

```
print dir/*(/on[230])
```

Explanation:

- `/` : match directories
- `on` : sort in ascending **o**rder by **n**ame (for descending order, use upper-case `O`)
- `[230]` : limit the results to the given range

The range qualifier is more generally of the form `[m,n]` - you could also use `[230,230]` in this context.

---

If you need to do it in `bash` then external tools are required: here's a method that should be safe for any filenames (even ones with embedded newlines):

```
printf '%s\0' dir/*/ | sort -z | awk -vRS='\0' 'NR==230 {print; exit}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposably you are using ubuntu , so nautilus is your file browser . If so then CTRL+F and type folder name. But as you said folder are not  explicitly in numbers but you can change on right upper corner to show folder by details instead icons ,then chose modified by date.

Comment: sorry for confusion I'm working on cli